# login with google plus using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to login with google plus using javascript,below is my code

index.html

Here i placed all scripts,html code

```
<html>
       
      <title>Login With google plus</title>
      <meta name="google-signin-client_id" 
      content="aaaaaaaaaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com ">

     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js? 
     onload=renderButton" async defer></script>

       <script>
          function onSuccess(googleUser) {
          var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
          gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
          var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
         'userId': 'me'
          });
   
        request.execute(function (resp) {
        var profileHTML = '<div class="profile"><div class="head">Welcome 
        '+resp.name.givenName+'! <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
        onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a></div>';
        profileHTML += '<img src="'+resp.image.url+'"/><div 
        class="proDetails"><p>'+resp.displayName+'</p> 
        <p>'+resp.emails[0].value+'</p><p>'+resp.gender+'</p> 
        <p>'+resp.id+'</p><p><a href="'+resp.url+'">View Google+ Profile</a> 
        </p></div></div>';
        $('.userContent').html(profileHTML);
        $('#gSignIn').slideUp('slow');
        });
      });
     }
     function onFailure(error) {
        alert(error);
         }
      function renderButton() {
             gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
             'scope': 'profile email',
             'width': 240,
             'height': 50,
             'longtitle': true,
             'theme': 'dark',
             'onsuccess': onSuccess,
             'onfailure': onFailure
        });
      }
     function signOut() {
         var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
         auth2.signOut().then(function () {
         $('.userContent').html('');
         $('#gSignIn').slideDown('slow');
     });
   }
  </script>

 <div id="gSignIn"></div>

 <div class="userContent"></div>

</html>
```

but when i want to login this error will show.

> 401. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_client
>
> The OAuth client was not found.

I can't get this error, please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Make sure that at Google console, project is *published*, project's return url is valid, etc. Issue is related to config.

Comment: no i am not give any url in authorized redirect url ,i am give http://localhost in Authorized JavaScript origins

Comment: url needs to be absolute including ports

Comment: it also return same error ,after giving redirect url

Comment: [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your application with google console to be able to use the OAuth, You will have to specify the return url after OAuth is granted by the client

Comment: it will return an error as Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.